# What happens when I create a file in the directory that is being archived with tar?

Tags: tar, compression, archive

I have a large directory (80GB) that I want to compress into the archive. What happens, when a new file is created in that directory, while it is being tared? Would new files be included in the created archive?

My OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4.

`tar --version`: (GNU tar) 1.29

Comment: The tar archive takes list of files present at start of the process, so if new files arrives, it is not taken in the tar archive. you then must update the tar archive to include that new file.

Comment: @francoisP That is only true for a flat directory, not for one with subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran `tar (GNU tar) 1.32` through `strace` and it shows this behaviour:

1. `tar` reads the whole list of files in a directory before it reads the first file from that directory.
2. The files from another directory (subdirectory or additional argument) are read only after the content of the directory which was handled before, has been completely written to the tar file.

So the answer to your question depends on the path where the new file is created. If the processing of its parent has already begun then it does not become part of the archive, otherwise it does.

Maybe snapshots are useful in your situation. Or (if that is not possible) reading all non-directory paths with `find` and feeding them to `tar`. Both approaches would prevent the adding of files which are created after the start of `tar`.

Comment: Other anomalies are possible and can be harder to deal with. A file that has been noted for inclusion in an archive may be deleted, renamed, truncated, or be continuously appended to, before or while it is being archived. Tar will generally report inconsistencies, complete the archive as best it can, return an error status code, and refer you to earlier errors.